# Difference between canonical and normal matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, jordan-normal-form

What is the difference between Normal forms and Canonical forms of matrices?

Examples and further readings would be of great help thank you!

Edit: Originally this was a question concerning the difference between Jordan Canonical Form and Jordan Normal form but it was pointed out that those are the same.  Similar post here: [Jordan Canonical Form. Jordan Normal Form.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2276209/jordan-canonical-form-jordan-normal-form)

Comment: In the common usage of these terms, there is no difference between the "Jordan normal form" (JNF) and the "Jordan canonical form" (JCF). However, there are matrix "normal forms" and "canonical forms" that have nothing to do with the JNF (for example, the [Frobenius normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form)). If your professor uses the terms JNF and JCF to mean different things, then your professor is doing something that is not widely done in the mathematical community.

Comment: They're the same.

Comment: Ok then I will edit my question then to ask what the difference between Normal and Canonical forms are.

Comment: They're the same also.

Comment: Even if they are not Jordan matrices?